# How to Host two react js application on single application pool?

Tags: reactjs, iis, hosting

I am trying to host two react applications under Default Web site in IIS?
ex. if the domain is test.com
The URL for both sites is like
test.com/React1
test.com/React2
**Image 1**
[image: testweb1 & testweb2 both are react website]
**Image 2**
[image: Build folder in testweb2]
**Image 3**
[image: In browser it shows blank]
**Image 4**
[image: I update index.html for "static/" to "./static/"]
**Image 5**
If we refresh the Page in Image 4 we get the following.
[image: 404 error]

Comment: Then have you tried and what's the real issue here?

Comment: At time if I map static folder of one website then only that website works. for second it will shows 404 error. For one website i cannot map two physical path.

Comment: Your description is ambiguous. Can you share a sequence of screenshots to illustrate further?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the react app as sub-application in iis then you need to do below settings:

Convert all absolute links to relative ones.

```
<link href="/static/css/main.584f321a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="./static/css/main.584f321a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image]

Comment: Not working. It is working fine if I host like react1.test.com & react2.test.com that I don't want

Comment: could you please share your browser network tab and consol snapshot, and your site binding detail, folder structure snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using yarn to build your app. You have to add two things in your package.json file.
First add the homepage value into package.json at the same level of name value

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "hompage" : "/SitePrefix"
  ...
}
```

In your case you have 2 sites testweb1 and testweb2. So, you have to change /SitePrefix by /testweb1 or /testweb2 in their package.json respectively. Then add a command to compile your project so You have to set de variable PUBLIC_URL (it appears at index.html file of public folder like %PUBLIC_URL%). You must change the value of that variable to be overwritten in the final index.html file. so add the build-prod-env command in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-prod-env": "set PUBLIC_URL=/testweb1&&yarn build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Don't add spaces between /testweb1 and && because it is going to affect your compile process. Publish your app and do the same with the other page changing the PUBLIC_URL variable.